# Running a live server through CMD vs Extension on Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

So currently I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS. I'm using several different resources (books, youtube, Udemy, Sololearn) just to keep everything covered and potentially fill in the gaps that other resources might not address.

Through the book that I'm reading, I ended up downloading sample codes. These sample codes have packages inside them. After following the instructions in the book and lots of googling I finally managed to download Node.js and I just copy and paste packages that came with the sample codes into my own exercise folders and then run CMD and run an npm start command to start the live server and show the content of html codes on the default browser...now, I was wondering, is there actually a point in doing it this way when there is a perfectly built live server extension that can be added onto Visual Studio Code? Not quite sure if I've missed something...the book is not exactly beginner friendly but it doesn't explain why go through all of this when you can just install the live server on VS Code and click on view in live server. If it helps, the book was written in 2016, so now wondering if live server was available back then in VS Code?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Think OP is asking what is the point of installing `live-server` via npm and then running the command from the terminal to start the live server vs simply using VS Code's 'Live Server' plugin. If so then I'd say this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369819/difference-between-vscode-live-server-and-node-live-server) question.